# Error when use PropertyNotInList in Grails + Oracle + CLOB

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to retrieve all objects from oracle 11g database except some objects that contain an especial value in a property.

The code:

```
//Retrieve thoughts
def thoughts = Question.findAllByThoughtsNotInList(["-", "", null], params)
def totalThoughts = Question.countByThoughtsNotInList(["-", "", null])
```

The attribute `thoughts` must be `CLOB` because I just have permission to CRUD data. I can't use any DDL statement.

With that, I got `ORA-00932` error.

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
```

My Domain Class:

```
class Question {
    String person
    String thoughts 

    static constraints = {
        thoughts nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        table "Question"
        id name: "person"
        person column: "person"
        thoughts column: "thoughts_person"
        version false
    }
}
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: The mappings are little confusing. `id` for `Question` is `person`? where is `thoughts` mapped to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thoughts` should be of `type: "text"` in the domain class if it is treated as CLOB. Can you share the `Question` domain class? And why `params` in the dynamic finder?

Something like this:

```
class Question {
    String thoughts 

    static mapping = {
        table "QUESTION"
        id column: "QUESTION_ID"
        thoughts column: "THOUGHTS", type: "text"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at my edit. Hopefully I conveyed what I wanted to.